# How can I compare file structures before and after a software install?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, uti, homebrew

I'm writing a new formula for Homebrew for some software I maintain and as part of my testing I'd like to ensure that files are *only* added to the correct places on install and that *all* files are removed on uninstall.

What's the best way of going about comparing file structures before and after my test installs and uninstalls?

Comment: Obviously not what you asked for, but still useful for a similar task is 'lsbom'.

Answer (score 2):

In Terminal I can think of two choice:

1. `ls -R`.
2. `tree directory-name/` (after you install it; i.e. `brew install tree`). The slash at the end preserves the display of special characters in the file the output is saved to.

In both case you redirect the output to a file before and after installation and compare the two files possibly using Apple FileMerge.app shipped with Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

I like using "find" and "shasum" for this sort of task.  Two different invocations, 1 for the structure, and another for the sha-1's of the files:

```
find -s /path/to/directory -ls > files-before.txt
find -s /path/to/directory -type f -exec shasum \{} \+ >> files-before.txt
```

Run your installs/uninstalls, and then use the same process to "files-after.txt".  Then

```
diff files-before.txt files-after.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways occur to me off the top of my head:

- [fseventer](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart) is an app that uses Apple's FSEvents framework to watch the filesytem change live. Be sure to read the warnings and caveats on the developer's website.
- Make a copy of the relevant directories (to someplace convenient, like your desktop) before performing the action. You can then use FileMerge (comes with the developer utilities) to compare directories.