# How to compare files for an entire drive from a before and after (or changes during) state?

Tags: command-line, macos, filesystem

I would actually very much like an option similar to `fseventer`, but it appears that not only will it support recent OS releases, but that it is altogether [no longer available](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start).

What can I do for 10.10 and later to reproduce the tool's function of listing near-live file system change events?

My first attempt to make a before and after comparison with every file on a drive from one state to the next.  So far all that I've come up with is something [like the following](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/42536/13220):

```
find -s / -ls > ~/files-before.txt
find -s / -type f -exec shasum \{} \+ >> ~/files-before.txt

### Do Stuff ###

find -s / -ls > ~/files-after.txt
find -s / -type f -exec shasum \{} \+ >> ~/files-after.txt

diff files-before.txt files-after.txt
```

But I can't help but think that there must be a better way to really get these results or perhaps to get a realtime presentation of changes over a span of time.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you be a little specific about what OS version you are targeting?

Comment: Well I would prefer `10.11` or `10.10`. I am specifically working on `10.11` at the moment.

Comment: fs_usage is sort of the command line equivalent of fseventer. It works on 10.10, don't know about 10.11 though. It can produce a *lot* of output, so do a man fs_usage to know how to limit that output somewhat.

Comment: Well, yeah, `fs_usage` is a little more verbose and lacks some easy realtime filtering since you have to `grep` the crap out of it, but it could be workable.